# Weird issues with RX on .NET 4.5 and F#

Tags: .net, f#, system.reactive

This is very odd.

I have two projects both F#.  I've installed the latest stable (2.1.30214.0) release of RX via NUGET.

In on project everything is absolutely fine.  In the other project I am basically getting errors everywhere because of the following.

```
Error   1   The type 'IObservable`1' is required here and is unavailable.
            You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, 
            Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.`
```

This really doesn't make sense as the source is fine and works perfectly in VS2010.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do a diff on the .fsproj files! Especially compare the list of `<Reference ../>`

Comment: I've encountered the same problem today. Basically, I have red squigglies all over, but the strange thing is that they go away when I compile. My code still compiles and runs, but as soon as I'm back in the editor, the squigglies reappear.

Answer (score 7):

As noted by @Mark Seemann, the problem stems from the fact that the Rx NuGet package for .NET 4.5 is actually a portable library.

Unfortunately, F# 3.0 doesn't support .NET 4.5-based portable libraries, only the legacy ones. Support for the newer portable libraries (also called .NETCore-based libraries) was added in [VS 2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2013/06/27/announcing-a-pre-release-of-f-3-1-and-the-visual-f-tools-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx).

So, you have 2 options:

- Build the Release45 or Debug45 target of Rx.sln in the [Rx open-source release](http://rx.codeplex.com) and use that instead of the Rx NuGet packages.
- Use F# 3.1 which is available in Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 2):

I have the issue too, I fixed it by editing the fsproj and replacing Net45 with Net40 in all the reactive dll paths.  This is required in spite of the following in my fsproj file:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

---

**Original answer:**

My earlier fix made the project compile but I couldn't use RX (quite pointless) but is below.

The errors are coming from the line:

```
open System
```

Now I have:

```
//open System
type Array = System.Array
type Double = System.Double
type TimeSpan = System.TimeSpan
```

All works!  Horribly ugly though, and it afflicts all files in the project.

Comment: +1 Changing the hint path to Net40 also worked for me, although it doesn't feel safe to do so :( I digged a little into the NuGet packages, and discovered that the Net40 binaries are 'true' .NET libraries, while the Net45 binaries are portable libraries. It seems that F# 4.5 projects don't like referencing portable libraries...

Comment: FWIW, I've added this issue on the Rx project site: https://rx.codeplex.com/workitem/47

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you reference the 4.5 DLLs in a 4.0 project or vice-versa. Make sure you're referencing the right version.

Comment: Definitely a 4.5 project.  I've instructed nuget to install to 2 projects, both are 4.5.  One works, one does not.  Tried re-creating them from scratch as well.  Is there something I can look at in the project file to double check?

Comment: Check your fsproj file. I had same problems and had to manually edit project file. You can add <HintPath>..\packages\Rx-Core.2.1.30214.0\lib\Net45\System.Reactive.Core.dll</HintPath>

Comment: Click on System.Reactive.Linq reference, hit F4, look at the path and make sure it has Net45 in it

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the infamous nuget/F# bug which Mike documents here, is it?

http://mikehadlow.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/nuget-install-is-broken-with-f.html